# Routing errors when adding an Admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

I added an Admin namespace to my app so when logging in to the administration area, it would have to be like this: admin/websites and admin/page/8

So this is what I have in my routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do |admin|
  match '/' => 'dashboard#index'
  resources :websites
  resources :pages
  resources :sessions
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'login'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'  
end
```

I have admin_controller.rb in app/controllers directory.

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  include UrlHelper
  ...
```

I created an admin directory inside app/controllers. So I have this inside app/controllers/admin/websites_controller.rb

```
class Admin::WebsitesController < ApplicationController
```

Some other answers suggested class Admin::WebsitesController < Admin::BaseController, but that never worked for me. If I'm wrong please let me know.

So then in my layout file (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) I have links like this one `edit_admin_website_path(@website)` that give me routing errors `Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/websites"}` Whyyyy?! :(

Comment: the url options this error returns usually should be `{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/websites", :id => 3}` or whatever the id is, could you check if: `@website` is not nil and `@website` is persisted (not `new_record?`)

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: a neat trick: if you find `edit_admin_website_path(@website)` to be too verbose, you can use (at least for url / link helpers): `[:edit, :admin, @website]`

Comment: You're right! I made a change to application_controller and @website wasn't being loaded anymore. So I just created a current_website helper method and used it on edit_admin_website_path instead, like this edit_admin_website_path(current_website) Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 3):

Add a file named **application_controller.rb** in the admin directory with this content:

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
end
```

Then, for each controller on this directory, extend the Admin::ApplicationController class.

Did you try this?

```
admin_edit_website_path(@website)
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. :)

Comment: Sorry about the path, I had made a change in the controllers and @website wasn't being loaded anymore. So I just created a helped method available to all controllers called current_website and coded this instead admin_edit_website_path(current_website)

Comment: Why would this approach be considered better?

Comment: @leonel, it's just tidier organization, the structure of the controllers/admin folder mirrors that of its parent. The base class is still called ApplicationController, it's just the namespace that changes...

Answer (score 1):

Rails namespaces rely on folder structure for loading the right classes. You should structure it like this:

```
app/controllers
  admin_controller.rb # class AdminController < ApplicationController

app/controllers/admin
  websites_controller.rb # class Admin::WebsitesController < AdminController
```

The `AdminController` should be defined outside the admin folder. If put it in there you'd have to refer to it as `Admin::AdminController` which is a little odd. In fact, you could call it `AdminNamespaceController` to be clear.

You can also use `rails generate` which will set things up for you in the expected places, although I don't think it creates the namespace base class for you to inherit from.